# Decrypting certain fields from a mysql database

Tags: mysql, encryption, encoding

I am trying to decrypt certain fields from a mysql database and display the results in the browser. I am able to decrypt some fields and get the right results but certain fields like zipcode and phone number displays unusual text; for example: R���d ��p(L�F�ò�S?�M��}�. Fields like email, name, city display correctly. The encryption and decryption uses base 64encoding and decoding. How can i rectify this issue. Thanks Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0):

If it is the same encrypt and decrypt you use for all the fields then it should work, you may want to cross check that.

It looks like the decryption is successful, so the problem could be encoding. You can cross check and confirm encoding before encryption and decoding after encryption are same.

Do you have a sample code which has this issue? This will help pinpoint.